# Q&A session with Denny Conn

Tags: discussion

The Homebrew SE site is very fortunate to have Denny Conn as a moderator and regular contributor, answering questions and providing guidance on this site on a daily basis. With hundreds of batches of beer to his credit, Denny has a vast knowledge of homebrewing, spanning everything from brewing techniques to recipe formulation.

Denny has kindly agreed to take part in a Q&A session in the **[Homebrew SE chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/199/homebrew)** on **September 25**, 2013 at 1 pm PST.

If there are topics you'd like discussed please vote it up below - or add it as a new answer if not already there.

Hope to see you there on the 25th!

Answer (score 2):

Techniques to improve mash efficiency

Answer (score 2):

Sparging - differences between no sparging, batch sparging and fly sparging. Which is best for a beginning brewer?

Answer (score 2):

Yeast - harvesting and reusing yeast

Answer (score 1):

Steps homebrewers can take to improve the quality of the beer

Answer (score 1):

Yeast - yeast starters - to do or not to do?

Answer (score 1):

Head retention - How to improve it.